# how to build an ansible inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I need some structure in ansible inventory to do something like this:

I have multiple addresses (with different items) and every address has multiple queues (with different items) how can I build the inventory file for this.

something like this:

```
addresses:
  - name: "a-address"
    type: "anycast"
    read_username: "read"
    read_password: "xxxxx"
    write_username: "write"
    write_password: "xxxx"
    - queue_name: "a-queue1"
      queue_type: xxxx
    - queue_name: "a_queue2"
      queue_type: xvx
  - name: "b-address"
    type: "multicast"
    read_username: "readb"
    read_password: "xxxxx"
    write_username: "writeb"
    write_password: "xxxx"
    - queue_name: "b-queue1"
      queue_type: xvx
    - queue_name: "b_que
```

How can I do this and how should I walk through this in ansible?

Comment: Similar to how you have `addresses:` then a list under that, you'll want to have `queues:` with your list of queues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: **"*How can I build the inventory file?*"**

A: This is the [YAML version](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#inheriting-variable-values-group-variables-for-groups-of-groups) of the inventory. I've added the variable *queues* to make it a valid YAML

```yaml
shell> cat hosts.yml
all:
  hosts:
    a-address:
      type: anycast
      read_username: read
      read_password: xxxxx
      write_username: write
      write_password: xxxx
      queues:
        - queue_name: a-queue1
          queue_type: xxxx
        - queue_name: a_queue2
          queue_type: xvx
    b-address:
      type: multicast
      read_username: readb
      read_password: xxxxx
      write_username: writeb
      write_password: xxxx
      queues:
        - queue_name: b-queue1
          queue_type: xxxx
        - queue_name: b_queue2
          queue_type: xvx
```

For example, the playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: type
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
ok: [a-address] => 
  type: anycast
ok: [b-address] => 
  type: multicast
```

---

Q: **"*Loop over addresses and within that loop a loop over the queues.*"**

A: The playbook below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - include_vars: hosts.yml
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ item.0.key }} {{ item.1 }}"
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ all.hosts|dict2items }}"
        - value.queues
```

gives(abridged)

```yaml
msg: 'a-address {''queue_name'': ''a-queue1'', ''queue_type'': ''xxxx''}'
msg: 'a-address {''queue_name'': ''a_queue2'', ''queue_type'': ''xvx''}'
msg: 'b-address {''queue_name'': ''b-queue1'', ''queue_type'': ''xxxx''}'
msg: 'b-address {''queue_name'': ''b_queue2'', ''queue_type'': ''xvx''}'
```

Comment: Vladimir, it is not the inventory but an property file (my mistake) and I want to do a loop over addresses  and within that loop a loop over the queues is this possible?

Comment: Yes. It's possible.